# unknown space between the digits after echo command

Tags: scripts

I have three data text files:

year:

```
2014
2014
2014
```

month:

```
03
03
03
```

day:

```
08
09
10
```

I use this function to combine them into a date:

```
function pl {                
  sed -n "$1p" $2
}

for (( j=1; j <= 3; j++ ))
do
    yr=$(pl $j year)
    mnth=$(pl $j month)
    dy=$(pl $j day)
    date_format=$yr-$mnth-$dy
    echo $date_format
done
```

My output, however, looks like:

```
2014 -03-08
2014 -03-09
2014 -03-10
```

I need to remove the space between "2014" and "-". The other codes use the $date_format so there should be no any space between the characters.

Comment: Why don't you just say `paste -d"-" year month day`? You have quite a lot of [to me unnecessary] code.

Comment: fyi, I just tried your code and gives me proper results -`2014-03-08 2014-03-09 2014-03-10`. Maybe you have a blank after 2014 in file *year*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick solution to getting rid of whitespace in your `$date_format` variable:

```
date_format=${date_format//[[:space:]]/}
echo "$date_format"
```

Comment: How can I save the date_format for creating loop after that

Comment: Not sure I perfectly understand what you need, but you can store `date_format` in another variable for later use.

Comment: sorry my mistake

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting that output, you have a trailing space in your `year` file. This works exactly as expected if you don't:

```
$ printf "2013\n2013\n2013\n" > year; printf "03\n03\n03\n" "03" > month; printf "08\n09\n10\n" > day
$ for (( j=1; j <= 3; j++ )); do
    yr=$(pl $j year)
    mnth=$(pl $j month)
    dy=$(pl $j day)
    date_format=$yr-$mnth-$dy
    echo $date_format
done
2013-03-08
2013-03-09
2013-03-10
```

And, if you add a trailing space:

```
$ printf "%s2013 \n2013 \n2013 \n" > year
$ for (( j=1; j <= 3; j++ )); do
>     yr=$(pl $j year)
>     mnth=$(pl $j month)
>     dy=$(pl $j day)
>     date_format=$yr-$mnth-$dy
>     echo $date_format
> done
2013 -03-08
2013 -03-09
2013 -03-10
```

So, the simplest solution is to remove the space from your input file:

```
sed -i 's/ *$//' year
```

Note, however, that you are using a very complex solution to a very simple problem:

```
$ paste -d"-" year month day | tr -d ' '
2013-03-08
2013-03-09
2013-03-10
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove everything after the year / month / day directly in the `sed` command;

In the `pl()` function replace

```
sed -n "$1p" $2
```

with

```
sed -n "$1s/\([0-9]*\).*/\1/p" $2
```

Comment: it gives -- lines, i mean doesn't work properly

Comment: this time gives; 2014--

Comment: @deepblue_86 My bad, my first command(s) were actually wrong. This should work.